# Javascript if condition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I create a script that have a loop action and put a condition where to stop this script. The first `if` is working properly, but not the second one, when I set `maxClick`, the script ignore the `if` condition and continue run the script.

Here's the full of my script

```js
var className   = ".link" ;
var delay       = 0.1 * 1000 ; //0.1 Seconds
var maxClick     = 5;


//Bind event handler
var element = document.querySelectorAll(className);
for (var j = 0; j < element.length; j++) {
    element[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Optional Function On Click Event
    }, false)
}

var i = 0 ;
function change() {
    if (i == maxClick ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("Clicked Link: " + element.length);
    }
    if (i == element.length && interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("Clicked Link: " + element.length);
    }
    element[i++].click();
}

change();
var interval = setInterval(change, delay);
```

```html
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
<a class="link">Link</a>
```

**[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bjz74jy/)**

Comment: what's your expected output to be?

Comment: it should show me alert "Clicked Link: 5" according to maxClick variable

Comment: use `alert("Clicked Link: " + i);` instead of `alert("Clicked Link: " + element.length);`

Comment: Oh my god!! what the little mistake from me XD

Comment: I think @Tolgahan is correct. element.length is always = 1

Comment: Thanks !! @TolgahanAlbayrak

Comment: Can you merge that two if condition to one? I tried it but not working, and can you put on an answer? And then I can accpet your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your code runs correctly. When `(i == maxClick )` the `interval` is cleared therefore the second `if` block does not get executed. I'm assuming you're confused since you're using the same alert value in both blocks. Try doing this instead:

```
if (i == maxClick ) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("Clicked Link: " + i);
}
```